# JavaScript Syntax - Listbox onChange Event

Tags: javascript, listbox

First, please forgive me, as I know very little about JavaScript, and am trying to make something work without knowing proper terms and syntax.  I am working within the CMS called "ViArt."  A lot of what is going on is handled by php, and I only have access in ViArt to add JavaScript to an onChange event for a listbox.

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

The product is sunglasses.  Different frame colors in a listbox 1 are designated by a numerical prefix.  There are 30 different lens color options for each frame color, and these lens colors are chosen in listbox 2.

Using my current code, for each frame, I have to go in the JavaScript for each frame and manually enter the numerical prefix designated to that frame.

This is my current, working code in an onChange event:

```
=================================
var FrameNo = '01';//ENTER FRAME NUMBER
var ImagePath = 'images/GlassesBrand/Rx/GlassesTest/';//ENTER PATH TO IMAGES
var ImageNamePrefix = 'GlassesTest-XL';//ENTER NAMING CONVENTION


// This changes the IMAGE hyperlink to larger image to match user's selection
document.getElementById('blackImg').href=ImagePath + 'Large/' + ImageNamePrefix + '-Frame' + FrameNo + '-Lens' + 
 this.form.property{form_id}_{property_id}.options[this.form.property{form_id}_{property_id}.selectedIndex].text.substrin    g(0,2) + '.jpg';
```

=================================
The change I want to make, is that I don't want to have to hard-code "FrameNo."  I want to call that dynamically within the onChange event, by looking up the selectedIndex of listbox 1.

=============================

In an onChange event for list box 2, named "{property_id}," I am trying to get the selectedIndex of a listbox 1, named "{property_parent_id6385_6773}"

{form_id} value is 6385

{property_id} is listbox 2, and in this example, the value is 6773

{property_parent_id6385_6773} value is 6765, and in this example, this refers to listbox 1

{property_parent_id6385_6773} is named dynamically by a php script or something.  For example, on the next form, it may be called {property_parent_id6400_6800}.  So I am trying to program the JavaScript to dynamically refer to the property_parent_id####_####, based on whatever form and list box I'm working with.

When I hard-code or semi-hard code it for testing, the following methods work:

```
this.form.property6385_6765.selectedIndex;
```

and

```
this.form.property{form_id}_6765.selectedIndex;
```

I don't know the syntax, so I thought declaring some things in variables might help me get what I needed.

From my notes:

```
var FrameBox = [this.form.property_parent_id6385_6773.value];    //WHICH EQUALS "6765"
var FrameNo = 'this.form.property' + {form_id} + '_' + FrameBox + '.selectedIndex';
```

RESULTS IN:

http://www.companyname.com/images/GlassesBrand/Rx/GlassesTest/Large/GlassesBrand-GlassesTest-XL-Framethis.form.property6385_6765.selectedIndex-Lens02.jpg

Whereas, an example of the result I am seeking is:

http://www.companyname.com/images/GlassesBrand/Rx/GlassesTest/Large/GlassesBrand-GlassesTest-XL-Frame1-Lens02.jpg

==============================

In summary, I know what I need, but I don't understand enough of the syntax.

I know this could be better phrased, but this is all new to me.  On the bright side, I am now inspired to take a class in JavaScript.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This looks more like an issue about how ViArt works. Have you tried the ViArt Forum.

Comment: I haven't yet. Trying to get a login there. I'm pretty sure my primary issue is one of JavaScript syntax. I'm just not sure I'm explaining it well.

Comment: Some of the syntax used to reference elements, ie {form_id} is specific to ViArt so do not see how you reference the frames color element.

Comment: have had a go at an answer but little more than an educated guess.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a calculated guess but could be worth a try.

```
this.form.property_parent_id{form_id}_{property_id}.options[this.form.property_parent_id{form_id}_{property_id}.selectedIndex].text
```